# Не изменяются байты при записи их через WriteProcessMemory();

Tags: c#

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint dwSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var pcor = Process.GetProcesses();
    Process[] proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    var staticBall_adress = 0x0648E1D4;
    byte[] ball = { 0xC8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00};
    var size = 4;
    var dummy = new UIntPtr();
    var handle = OpenProcess(0x001F0FFF, false, proc[0].Id);

    WriteProcessMemory(handle, (IntPtr)staticBall_adress, ball, (uint)size, out dummy);

    CloseHandle(handle);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

не записывается ни в какую, handle взял, адрес указал, байты и размер тоже, но при запуске кода байты в программе не записываются

Comment: Вызвав ваш код, получил ошибку: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800701E7): Попытка обращения к неверному адресу. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800701E7)`, что вы пытаетесь записать?

Comment: Байты по адресу 0648E1D4, у меня никакой ошибки не возникает, компилится, но безрезультатно

Comment: В код свой добавьте: if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() != 0)
            {
                var tmp = Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error()).ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(tmp, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

Comment: Код работает в WinForms, а в консоли не работает